# Only Administrators can logon through Remote Desktop Services

Tags: active-directory, remote-desktop-services, windows-server-2022

I have a domain with 3 VM's: domain controller, workstation and application server. RDP connections to the workstation were working fine until I installed license server (we need more CALs) and remote desktop session host on the workstation + I might have made a configuration or two that is causing the problem trying to debug why the license server was not assigning any CALs.

Currently only users who I add to the Builtin "Administrators" Security Group can logon. Other users get the error "the requested session access is denied".

**Relevant configurations are listed below**
Local Security Policy (workstation): I have configured "Allow log on through Remote Desktop Services" to include the AD group I am adding users to (RDP Workstation) + the Builtin "Remote Desktop Users":

Control Panel (workstation) > System and Security > Allow remote access: Same AD group has been added (RDP Workstation)

Default Domain Policy: Policies > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Remote Desktop Services > Remote Desktop Session Host > Licensing: Use the specified Remote Desktop license servers = Enabled, Set the Remote Desktop licensing mode = Enabled

**EDIT 1:** did a "gpresult /v" being logged on with my own user, which is part of the Builtin Administrators group. "Resultant Set Of Policies for User" all contained N/A.

[gpresult](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QF2Kq.png)
[gpresult](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXRRK.png)

**EDIT 2:**

[gwmi -namespace "Root/CIMV2/TerminalServices"  Win32_TerminalServiceSetting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7y6Vo.png)

[Added terminalServerMode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQsKA.png)

Comment: Per-user licenses are never enforced and never required. You should start with that, at least you can rule out licensing as a process of elimination.

Comment: Can you do a `gpresult /v` and show the applied policies on the machine where you want to logon? Or run a rsop query

Comment: @GregAskew then how do you enable more than two simultaneous logons?

Comment: @Turdie I added the results to the question. Does it give you any relevant informtion?

Comment: It sounds like the Remote Desktop Session Host feature may not be installed. Check that first: `gwmi -namespace "Root/CIMV2/TerminalServices"  Win32_TerminalServiceSetting`    
It should output 1.

Comment: This is freaking weird even the Default Domain Policy is not there, or is this machine not joined to a domain. Im totally lost

Comment: @GregAskew I updated the original question with the results

Comment: @Turdie I added an extra screenshot to EDIT 1. It is domain joined.

Comment: You are missing the TerminalServerMode property. If you expand that, it would be 1 if the host has the role installed. It doesn't. Also it's apparent from the server name that this is not a real system.

Comment: @GregAskew So if I enable TerminalServerMode it should work? What do you mean by "this is not a real system" ?

Comment: @GregAskew I added terminalServerMode. See new screenshot under EDIT 2

Answer (score 0):

I would reset the group policies of the machines (not the domain controller)

https://github.com/virtualox/Reset-GroupPolicy.ps1/blob/main/Reset-GroupPolicy.ps1

And then reboot the machine